# Search in *.mdf doesnt work

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I have a *. Mdf database that I will read into a GridView ... I will then give the user the ability to search for people (by surname). The code works fine until the search. When I enter a last name and think on search, then the error message from Catch up.

I am a total beginner in C # and humbly request serious answers.

Thanks in advance.

**My code**

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'baseballDataSet.Players' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.playersTableAdapter.Fill(this.baseballDataSet.Players);

    }

    private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchValue = sInput.Text;

        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                {
                    row.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: exc.Message, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: at what line ? At `if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should skip rows where row.IsNewRow == true in your foreach ... .Value is null there ...

```
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow) continue;

        if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        {
            ....
```